# Lines in a canvas are far too wide, why?

Tags: javascript, html

I saw a tutorial on how to draw a graph using a canvas with javascript on [this site](http://www.tutorialspark.com/html5/HTML5_Canvas_dataplot_Demo.php).

[Here is my translation of it](https://jsfiddle.net/ayc1zp0s/).

In mine, the lines are massive.

I tried to manipulate the options here:

```
sections = 5;
Val_max = 3;
Val_min = 0;
var stepSize = .5;
var columnSize = 50;
var rowSize = 50;
var margin = 1;
```

all to no avail.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Adding a scale transformation to the canvas also affects line widths. It’s best to do that part manually instead.

Comment: Simply add `context.lineWidth = 1 / yScale;` after your `context.scale()`